# How to read data from QNetworkReply being used by QWebPage?

Tags: qt, tee, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebkit, qwebpage

I use [`QWebPage`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwebpage.html) to download a webpage as well as all its resources. At the same time I'd like to get hold on raw data being downloaded by Qt during this process. Doing this by reading data from [`QNetworkReply`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html) in [`void QNetworkAccessManager::finished(QNetworkReply * reply)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#finished)
signal is not a good solution as data could have been already read by `QWebPage` itself. This is because

> QNetworkReply is a sequential-access
>   QIODevice, which means that once data
>   is read from the object, it no longer
>   kept by the device.

according to [detailed description](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkreply.html#details) of `QNetworkReply`.

However `QWebPage` can be configured to use custom [`QNetworkAccessManager`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qnetworkaccessmanager.html) with overriden `createRequest` method

```
QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest ( Operation op, const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0 )
```

I think the right solution would be to create a proxy for `QNetworkReply` and return it in the `createRequest` method. This proxy should allow for reading data from reply as is the case with the original `QNetworkReply` (so that `QWebPage` could read data from it) but at the same time this proxy should allow for reading data by other objects after it have been read by `QWebPage`. In other words we need [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) for `QNetworkReply`'s `IODevice` base class.

How to write this proxy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like someone has already wanted the same and wrote [a proxy for the QNetworkReply](http://gitorious.org/qtwebkit/performance/blobs/master/host-tools/mirror/main.cpp).

Comment: Hi Piotr, do you know if the proxy is still available somewhere? The link appears to be broken.

Comment: @izyda It looks like the link is only temporarliy unavailable - *The repositories will soon be available for read-only access, with original clone URLs preserved.*

Comment: Got it. On a side note, did you find that subclassing QtNetworkResponse is a better option than using peek()?