# Re-ordering the connection queue of Qobject

Tags: qt, signals, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebpage

I have a customized QNetworkAccessManager and a QWebPage class, now I want to read the reply data of each request retrieved by the QWebPage.

Now I connected the finished() signal, but since QWebPage connected it first, and the first finished() slot of QWebPage would read all the data from the QNetworkReply object, thus the slot in QNetworkAccessManager would read nothing at all.

So can I "insert" a connection to the list of QObject's connections, instead of appending it?

Comment: I won't say it's impossible, but as far as I know the connection list is a vector but it's held inside a `QObjectPrivate` class so it's not exposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if you were able to do that, the `QWebPage` wouldn't be able to read the data from the `QNetworkReply` object, because the reply is a sequential `QIODevice` and the data can only be read once.

The only way I've been able to deal with this is to override `QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest` and have it return a `QNetworkReply` subclass which acts as a a wrapper around the actual reply object, which can capture the incoming data.

Ah, see [How to read data from QNetworkReply being used by QWebPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475647/how-to-read-data-from-qnetworkreply-being-used-by-qwebpage) for a solution.