# How to download resources of a webpage using QWebPage?

Tags: qt, qnetworkaccessmanager, qwebkit, qwebpage, qnetworkreply

When **QWebPage** loads a page, it sends requests for all the objects in the page (images, js, css). I want to save these objects to separate files and not just to show them on QWebView.

As mentioned in [How to read data from QNetworkReply being used by QWebPage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475647/how-to-read-data-from-qnetworkreply-being-used-by-qwebpage), the data for each object is already read by **QWebPage** and the program gets nothing for writing to a file. The above link suggests to implement a **QNetworkReply** proxy and return it in **createRequest** method of a derived **QNetworkAccessManager** class. But, it's not clear to me what should I do in that createRequest method or how to implement that proxy for **QNetworkReply**. If you have a sample code for this purpose it would be great.

The above link suggested this link: [a proxy for the QNetworkReply](https://gitorious.org/qtwebkit/performance/source/50304e2aaf75529f4891d6a67d0f24c1773d98a8:host-tools/mirror/main.cpp). But it seems a complicated class for some other purpose and as I said I don't know how to use it in **createRequest** method.